# BufferedReader returns null, even though the stream it's reading from is at pos 0

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to pass data from a program `MainProgram` to another program `TestProgram` which I invoke using Reflection. For this, i re-route `Standard.in` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` containing the data I want to transmit. `TestProgram` then reads from `Standard.in` using a `BufferedReader` and `readLine()`. I execute the whole thing several times in a for-loop. The problem is this: The first time, everything works fine, from the second time on, `TestProgram` reads `null` from `System.in`. Java Documentation states that the `BufferedReader` will return `null`, if the end of stream is reached. But there is definitely data in the stream and the `pos` of my `ByteArrayOutputStream` is also 0. Why could the `BufferedReader` think that suddenly `System.in` is empty or at the end of stream?

Here is the code that's manipulating the streams and invoking the method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCases; i++) {

  Byte[] paramBytes = getCurrentParamBytes();

  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(paramBytes));

  System.setIn(inputStream);
  String[] params = null;

  testProgram.invoke(null, (Object) params);
}
```

Here is the code that's reading from `System.in`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String current = in.readLine();
```

I have assured myself of the state of `System.in` using the debugging mode of Eclipse and everything is fine there. The fact that it only reads `null` starting with the second invocation of the `TestProgram`'s main method is also very puzzling to me. Especially, because all values I have checked are exactly the same as they were the first time (except for the data in the stream, of course).

Sadly, I cannot change the use of the `BufferedReader` because `TestProgram` is not my class and has to be used as-is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is new `BufferedReader` created every time you invoke `testProgram.invoke`? Or only first time? If it is once than buffered reader continues to use `InputStream` you provided on first invocation .

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `BufferedReader`is only created once, but I don't know for sure. It is a static variable created in an external JAR that I include in the classpath and that is imported in `TestProgram`.  
I have tried creating inputStream before the for-loop, but this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely in the fact that `BufferedReader` created once, on first invocation. `BufferedReader` uses instance of `InputStream` that you provided on first iteration of a loop. On second, third, etc invocations it still uses this stream and doesn't read from updated `System.in`. I see 2 possible solutions if you can't modify source code of `TestProgram`.

1. Create new instance of `TestProgram` on each iteration instead of reusing old. It might help to "refresh" inner `BufferedReader` if it is stored as class variable, not static.
2. if you can't create new instance of `TestProgram` because it has state or `BufferedReader` stored in static variable you can try following: use special kind of `InputStream` that allows you to concatenate several `InputStreams` on fly. Check [ConcatInputStream](http://ostermiller.org/utils/doc/com/Ostermiller/util/ConcatInputStream.html).

Example of second approach:

```
ConcatInputStream concat = new ConcatInputStream();
System.setIn(concat);

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCases; i++) {

  Byte[] paramBytes = getCurrentParamBytes();

  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(paramBytes));

  concat.addInputStream(inputStream);
  String[] params = null;

  testProgram.invoke(null, (Object) params);
}
```

I'm not sure it will work because I don't know what is behaviour of BufferedReader if it sees end of stream on first invocation and then, on second invocation, stream suddenly not empty any more (because we've added new stream to `concat`). But hopefully it will work.

There are also third approach: you can decompile `TestProgram` using e.g. [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/) and find where instance of `BufferedReader` is stored. And then you can set it to null between iterations using reflections. But it's very error prone.

Comment: 1. I never create an instance of `TestProgram`, I'm merely invoking its main method. Additionaly, the `BufferedReader` is stored in a class from an external JAR-file, which is probably why it's not re-created with every invocation.  
2. I will probably try this if everything else fails.  
3. I tried this but got a `ClassNotFoundException`. The name I tried was `PackageName.ClassName`. Is there a special case if I try to access a JAR?

Comment: @Cecilya show you code where you're trying to access field via reflection.

Comment: Field reader = Class.forName("Package.ClassName").getDeclaredField("in"); // in = BufferedReader
      
reader.setAccessible(true);
      
Object oldValue = reader.get(Class.forName("Package.ClassName"));
      ioReader.set(oldValue, new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

(Sorry for the bad format.)

Comment: Finally tried the `ConcatInputStream` and it works! Thank you!